# pyinstaller failed to execute script , a simple script that worked with idle

Tags: python, pyinstaller, py2exe

i made a little tool to bind the ctrl+win+right arrow to a key in this code its F2 the probleme is when i try to use pyinstaller to make it an executable for my friends who wanted this tool , when i try to open the exe it said failed to execute the script . but it works properly with python idle
the code is :

````
from pynput.keyboard import Key , Controller

keyboard = Controller()

i=2

import keyboard
import time
def waitUntil(): #defines function
    wU = True
    while wU == True:
        if not keyboard.is_pressed("F2"): #checks the condition
            wU = False
        else:
            wU = True

while i == 2 :
    if keyboard.is_pressed("F2") :
        waitUntil()
        keyboard.press("Ctrl+cmd+Right")
        keyboard.release("Ctrl+cmd+Right")```
````

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to help here because ultimately Controller doesn't have an method called "is_pressed()".

Clean up your code as such:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Controller

keyboard = Controller()

def waitUntil(): #defines function
    wU = True
    while wU == True:
        if not keyboard.is_pressed("F2"): #checks the condition
            wU = False
        else:
            wU = True

while True :
    if keyboard.is_pressed("F2") :
        waitUntil()
        keyboard.press("Ctrl+cmd+Right")
        keyboard.release("Ctrl+cmd+Right")
```

and you should get the following error when run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oubnouquestion.py", line 14, in <module>
    if keyboard.is_pressed("F2") :
AttributeError: 'Controller' object has no attribute 'is_pressed'
```

At least this is what I get on Linux with the latest version of pynput. Thus, it broken even before I get to Pyinstaller. Are you sure this works in Idle?

Comment: im very sure i don't know why it doesn't work for u , but do u have an alternative

Comment: ps : i have windows 10